# ElasticSearch aggregations too slow

Tags: elasticsearch, duplicates, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have over 60mil docs in index.
I need to find item duplicates by hashes, inside one seller.
Seller have from 0 to ~2-3mil docs.

From aggregations, i need to have ids of duplicate items.

Index mapping:

```
    'mappings' => [
        'properties' => [
            'id' => [
                'type' => 'long'
            ],
            'item_hash' => [
                'type' => 'keyword'
            ],
            'seller_id' => [
                'type' => 'integer'
            ],
        ]
    ]
]
```

Aggregation Query

```
'index' => 'name of the index',
        'size' => 0,
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'term' => [
                    'seller_id' => id
                ]
            ],
            'aggs' => [
                'duplicates' => [
                    'terms' => [
                        'field' => 'item_hash',
                        'min_doc_count' => 2,
                        'size' => 250 
                        'include' => [
                            'partition' => $partition,
                            'num_partitions' => count_partitions
                        ]
                    ],
                    'aggs' => [
                        'duplicateDocuments' => [
                            'top_hits' => [
                                '_source' => [],
                                'size' => 10
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
            ]
        ]
```

Comment: Instead of using top_hits as the last sub-aggregation, maybe try a `terms` aggregation on the `id` field (if it's the same as the `_id` of the document)

Comment: @Val what exactly you mean. From 1st aggregation i have hashes that duplicates, from second i have ids of items that have this hashes. Terms on what?

Comment: Terms on the _id or id field, it's more efficient than using top_hits

Comment: @Val how i can use terms on _id field if i dont know ids of items that duplicates

Comment: You don't need to know the _ids that's what the terms aggregation in `duplicateDocuments` will tell you. it's just another way of retrieving those ids, but without using top_hits